# Why does this code crash at "temp[2]='X'?

Tags: c

```
int main(void) {
char *temp = "ABCDE";
temp[2] = 'X';
printf("%s", temp);
return 0;
}
```

In gdb I could see that temp[2] = 'X' is causing the crash. But why? Could some answer please?

Comment: Because bad things happen when you attempt to modify a "*string-literal*" perhaps using a *character array*, `char temp[] = "ABCDE";` would be a better choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String literals are *non-modifiable*. It may be stored in read-only section of the memory and any attempt to modify it will lead to undefined behavior.

If you want to modify it, declare `temp` as an array of `char`s

```
char temp[] = "ABCDE";
```

Comment: As a high rep user, you must know this is a dupe hundreds of times over

Comment: @DavidHeffernan; Can't  agree more.